# using flask+couchdb+couchbase lite

Tags: ionic-framework, flask, couchdb, couchbase-lite

I've been using couchdb + flask for my ionic app.

However, my requirements have changed slightly now and I have to store a lot of lookup files in the app (transferring them everytime is very painful and slow)...

is it possible for me to use couchbase lite alongside flask + couchdb for this?

I have been trying to get some documentation/example apps but there seems to be a dearth of good documentation on this specific issue... but from what i read, it is indeed possible to sync couchbase lite and couchdb.

Another specific question I have is can I use flask to sync the two databases rather than directly connect the couchbase lite and couchdb?

Regards,
Galeej

Answer (score 0):

Use base64 encode if the files are binary or just dump them as a document if they are a text file.

Say I have a file foo.txt with following content:

```
My name is stupid.
```

Then I would create a document in Couchbase-lite with key `foo.txt` and json would look like following:

```
{
    "content": "My name is stupid."
}
```

Now that string will be replaced with base64 string if file is binary. You will need to decode it before you can use it in application.

Comment: We considered that...but the issue is that some of the data changes often...so it would be cumbersome to change the files often... would it be possible to set up a system where couchbase lite talks to flask and updates the documents on the fly?

Comment: You can always update the "cotnent" value of a file in JSON using flask.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Couchbase Lite (currently) works with CouchDB.  Couchbase Lite implements CouchDB's replication protocol.

Regarding Flask, it depends on what you need.  To get all the features, I think you'd largely end up having to reproduce the replication protocol, which is tricky.

This link may help: [Couchbase-lite and CouchDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20489162/couchbase-lite-and-couchdb)